# Trouble with function that is supposed to find highest number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing

I have this program that is designed to help a maker of chips and salsa keep track of sales for five different types of salsa. There are two parallel arrays, the first being "names" and the second being "num_of_jars". In the "names" array there are the five types of salsa(“Mild”, “Medium”, “Sweet”, “Hot”, “Zesty”). The second array will have numbers the user needs to input. The program should prompt the user to enter the number of jars sold(into the num_of_jars array) for each type of salsa.. Once this sales data has been entered, the program should produce a report that displays sales for each salsa type, total sales, and the names of the highest selling product.I am almost done with the program, my only issue is with a function I made (find_max). This function is supposed to find which salsa had the highest sales report and output it. So for example. if the user input "100" for "Mild", "5" for "Medium", "10" for "sweet", "20" for "hot", and "1" for "zesty", the function will output something along the lines of "Best selling product is Mild". I'm still somewhat new to functions so keep that in mind please. Below is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const string names[] {"Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"};
int num_of_jars [5];
int find_max (const int a[], int n);

int main() {
  int total;
  int sum = 0;
  int v;
  
  // Loop for user input
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cout << "How many jars of" << " " << names[i] << " " << "sold? ";
    cin >> num_of_jars[i];
    }
  
  cout << endl;
  
  // Sales report table
  cout << "Salsa Sales Report" << endl;
  cout << "------------------" << endl;
  cout << names[0] << setw(14) << num_of_jars[0] << endl;
  cout << names[1] << setw(12) << num_of_jars[1] << endl;
  cout << names[2] << setw(13) << num_of_jars[2] << endl;
  cout << names[3] << setw(15) << num_of_jars[3] << endl;
  cout << names[4] << setw(13) << num_of_jars[4] << endl;

  // Loop for gathering total of jars sold 
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sum += num_of_jars[i];
    }
  
  cout << setw(18) << "-------" << endl;
  cout << "Total" << setw(13) << sum << endl;

  v = find_max(num_of_jars, 5);
  cout << v;

return 0;
}

// Function to find highest number
int find_max (const int a[], int n) {
  int max = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (a[i] > a[max])
      max = i;
      return max;
    }
```

This is the output so far

How many jars of Mild sold? 100
How many jars of Medium sold? 5
How many jars of Sweet sold? 10
How many jars of Hot sold? 20
How many jars of Zesty sold? 1

### Salsa Sales Report

Mild           100
Medium           5
Sweet           10
Hot             20
Zesty            1
-------
Total          136
0

The "0" at the very bottom is from the function I discussed earlier. I have not yet coded the functions output to say "Best selling product is...". I have just been testing to see what it would output, which in this case should've been "100". I feel that the array "names" should be included in the function but I am unsure.

Comment: IMHO, a `std::vector` of struct is better than parallel arrays.  Are you allowed to use structures?

Comment: You've written `find_max` in such a way that it returns the _index of_ the largest number, not the largest number itself. In this case, because the salsa with the most sales is at index `0`, it returns `0`. `num_of_jars[0]` is `100` and `names[0]` is `"Mild"`. I'd also suggest using `{}` braces even for one-line `if`s and `for`s because it leads to less readable, more brittle code to do it your way.

Comment: No I have not learned structures yet so I would like to stick with parallel arrays.

Comment: Okay, the function returning the index of the highest number makes sense. Any tips on how to get it to return the salsa type the number is parallel to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it returns the index of largest number not the actual number. If you want both and you are bound to not to use vectors than you can additionally pass an integer by reference for index.

You can make a slight change in your program.

```
int find_max(const int a[], int n,int &index) {
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] > a[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    index = max;
    return a[max];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does return the actual number, but not the name. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Once you have index, you can print the name from a main. e.g cout<<"Best selling product is "<<names[index];

Comment: and if you only want to print best selling product. you can use your old function which you written in your code can be used. As it is returning an index to highest value, and you only want that not the actual highest number.

Comment: For the function I went with what you wrote, and when calling it in main I wrote find_max(num_of_jars, 5);
  cout << "Best selling product is " << names[index];         This keeps outputting the first index in the names array, "Mild" even if other salsa types have higher numbers. Just to reiterate, I need to output the name of the highest salsa type. Thank you very much for your help so far though.

Comment: Because you are not passing index variable in function. just use your old function which you wrote and  call it like this.  cout << "best selling product is :" << names[find_max(num_of_jars,5)];

Comment: Okay, that did work. Thank you very much for your help!